# QML Calendar : Programmatically call onClicked handler

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

My QML application is displaying a Calendar element.

When the selected date is changed (clicked), I need to update an other element (an image).

I have something like this:

```
Calendar  {
    id: calCalendar

    onClicked: {
        // update other QML element
    }
}
```

It works fine when the user click with the mouse on the calendar: the other element (the image) is correctly updated.

My problem is initialization : when my app is started, the calendar displays the current date by default, and I'd like to programmatically call the onClicked handler, to make sure the image is up to date.

I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something when a QML component is done initializing you can use the `Component.onCompleted :` slot.

```
Calendar  {
    id: calCalendar

    onClicked: {
        // update other QML element
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
         // Do stuff for initialization.
         // you could do this here : calCalendar.Clicked()
         // if you want to use the same code for initialization and for user input handling later on.
    }
}
```

The point is the following : `onXXX : {` declares a slot to handle the singal `XXX`. Here the signal is `Clicked`. You can trigger the signal programmatically as you say, just by invoking it like a function. You'll need to know a valid overload for the arguments (if any).

Comment: Thanks, it is working as expected. Here is what I do in `Component.onCompleted:` `calCalendar.clicked(calCalendar.selectedDate)`